# Proving the Lebesgue decomposition theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The book I'm following proves that every measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ can be uniquely represented as $\mu = \mu_{discrete} + \mu_{abs.cont.} + \mu_{singular}$ using the notion of *candidate density* at one of the steps. That is, a candidate density is any function $g \geq 0$ such that $\int_E g d\lambda \leq \mu(E)$ for any Borel set $E$ (where $\mu$ is assumed to have no discrete component, which is easily achievable by subtraction).

Then the proof shows that for every pair of candidate densities $g_1, g_2$ their $\max(g_1, g_2)$ is also a candidate density: indeed, the claim is that
\begin{align*}
\int_E \max(g_1, g_2) d\lambda & = \int_{E \cap \{g_1 \geq g_2\}} g_1 d\lambda + \int_{E \cap \{g_1 < g_2\}} g_2 d\lambda \\
& \leq \mu(E \cap \{g_1 \geq g_2\}) + \mu(E \cap \{g_1 > g_2\}) = \mu (E).
\end{align*}
The question I'm having is I'm not sure the inequality is justified here. For it to hold by the definition of candidate density, $E \cap \{g_1 \geq g_2\}$ shall also be a Borel set, but what stops $g_1$ and $g_2$ from behaving badly enough so that $\{g_1 \geq g_2\}$ is not a Borel set, breaking the whole intersection?

Comment: Are you sure that $g$ isn't assumed to be a Borel function as part of the definition?

Comment: Nope, it literally goes as "To continue, call a function $g$ a candidate density if $g \geq 0$ and [the integral condition]". Anyway, that would just mean that the preimage of any Borel set is a Borel set, but it wouldn't imply that the set in question is a Borel set, would it?

Comment: Well, on a second thought the $g$ is surely a Borel function since otherwise the Lebesgue integral is not justified, but my previous question still holds then.

Comment: if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are Borel, then $\{g_1\geq g_2\}$ is Borel, even if $g_i=\pm\infty$ at some points. I can write a proof of this, but I think this is not your problem